# Avoid duplicates for producers and consumers on same topic

Tags: apache-kafka

This may sound like I'm doing it wrong, but to achieve failover capability I have algorithmically generated topic names, and multiple instances should at the same time consume and produce messages on the same topic. Data is eventually consistent, all data consumed is locally merged accordingly.

Though one problem I see with this approach is that I'd get a lot of duplicates, since messages produces for the topic need to be consumed again - even though the data has been produced locally and thus there is a need to avoid consuming self-crated data.

The obvious solution would be to choose a different topic hierarchy. But that would for algorithmic reasons (way how topics have to be identified in my case) mean quite some effort.

Is there a common pattern to this problem? Or is this problem in itself an anti-pattern?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem you're trying to solve. This only sounds like you're producing a bunch of data with unique **offsets** and duplicate _content_. I struggle to see how that helps with fail over... MirrorMaker2 has cluster fail over features, if that's something you need. Kafka itself has nothing to dedupe events

Comment: The problem is that all instances in one failover group (let‘s call it a region) are also in the same let‘s call it „data group“. All instances of a region have the same data, while any instance of that region can generate data related to that group - which all instances of that group should consume. Here, I want to avoid to have to consume data from that group by the instance which generated the data (and has it already locally).

Comment: I guess still not really understanding how Kafka fits in here. You have a list of events. Those events build up some state. You can consume those events multiple times to build different states, but you shouldn't "copy the state" themselves, only replicate the event-stream. That is natively handled by Kafka topic replication, but you can use MirrorMaker, like I said, to copy that out to external (maybe, "regional") Kafka clusters for higher availability or purposes of filtering/local-processing for "data groups"

Comment: Or you can write the data into a sharded / partitioned + geo-replicated database like Cassandra/Couchbase/CockroachDB , which then your clients will query for each appropriate "region". By using a database, you can also do some KV-lookup to check for duplicates